# nginx proxy_pass gives extra slash

Tags: nginx, web2py

I need to convert this:

```
http://mydomain.nl/wp/welcome
```

to this (to run web2py):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome
```

but this proxy:

```
location /wp {
           proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

results to this URL (according to the error.log):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000//welcome
```

I don't understand why the two consecutive slashes come from, this URL makes web2py say Bad Gateway. If I remove the final slash from the proxy_pass line, the `wp` appears in the output URL, which I understand.

How should I change the proxy_pass command?

Comment: See if `location /wp/ {` helps.

Comment: @alvits That did it. Thanks. In case you make this an `answer` I'd be glad to accept.